# Repository no longer has Release file during apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL1 on my Windows computer

When I try to run `apt-get update` I see the following in the output:

```
Err:8 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release
   404  Not Found [IP: 3.95.117.170 443]
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

I have tried the following solutions:

- `apt-get clean`: successful, but still can run apt-get update
- `apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories`: still get the same error
- `apt-get update && apt-get –yes –force-yes –fix-missing –auto-remove –allow-unauthenticated --allow-insecure-repositories –show-upgraded –option DPkg::Options::=“–force-confold” dist-upgrade`: same error

How can I run the update?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* earlier this year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/msantic), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the bad repo with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /"
sudo rm -fv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo rm -fv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list.save
sudo apt update
```

Comment: After a release goes EOSS (*end of standard support*) sources are free to *drop* support for it thus the issue is to be expected. Many build sites only allow standard accounts to build for supported releases, thus PPAs are either *stale* (unpatched) and *dropping* support is the recommended option. A better strategy is to move to a supported release; as errors only appear on the *dropped* sources, and **not** for the equally dangerous *stale* or *abandoned* sources.